editing a pose bone's custom property in python
I created a custom property prop for pose_bone which will get built with a rig in a script:
bpy.types.PoseBone.NewProp = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="New Property", default=0, min=0, max=0)
pose_bone.NewProp = 0

Now I am trying to write a tool that adds things to the pose bone and will need to modify the property's max value each time something is added.
pose_bone.id_properties_ui("NewProp").update(max=5) 
pose_bone.id_properties_ui("NewProp").as_dict()


{'subtype': 'NONE', 'min': -2147483648, 'max': 5, 'soft_min':
-2147483648, 'soft_max': 2, 'step': 1, 'default': 0}

So I can see in the property's dictionary that max is now 5, but when I try to set the property to 5 using either code or the UI, it stays at 0 still. Is there a step I'm missing or am I taking the wrong approach here? Ideally I'd like my script to query properties and update the max by one each time. I have all the logic written out, but it just seems like changing it in code doesn't work, or I'm missing a refresh step.
